# Admin 404's after migration, tried every solution I've found with no success

Tags: server-setup

I'm trying to help a friend migrate his magento site to a new host. I exported the DB, zipped the site files and moved everything over. There was a hiccup with the SQL on import, but I found a fix.

The DNS propagated and the front end works great, but the admin gives: https://sitedomain.com/index.php/admin. I try just /admin, and it redirects to that with this error:

> The server can not find the requested page:
>
> ```
> sitedomain.com/index.php/admin (port 443)
> ```

I've tried every fix you can find via google - running this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

...clearing caches, setting admin SSL to 0 from 1, nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do make sure that the default ".htaccess" file for Magento is copied over as well as it is always missed out due to it being a hidden dot file.

If you are sure that the proper ".htaccess" file is in place, make sure that the server's mod_rewrite is working properly.

Comment: Thanks - I was able to copy over .htaccess with the rest of the site files, and just checked on it, 'RewriteEngine on' is entered in it.

I did also create a test.php file with phpinfo(); in it, but don't see mod_rewrite there.

Comment: You may want to check with the hosting provider on whether mod_rewrite is enabled in the server and working properly.

Comment: Thank you, did exactly that. It was in fact related to .htaccess - I had the mod_rewrite line in, but the rewrite base line was incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it's resolved now!